# how to show video(with sound) in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

i'm not english so sorry for typing problems

i want to show videos with sound in my app but i don't know how to do it.

here's my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('darkgray12')
colors = (sg.theme_background_color(), sg.theme_background_color())


counter = 1
firstTime = True


def post():
    post = [sg.Frame('',[
        [sg.Image('',size=(600 ,600),key=f'-content-{counter}-')],
        [sg.Button('PLAY',key=f'-PLAY-KEY-{counter}-'),sg.Button('PAUSE',key=f'-PAUSE-KEY-{counter}-'),sg.Text('',key=f'-TIMER-{counter}-')]
    ],key=f'-POST-{counter}')]
    return post


layout = [
    [sg.Frame(title='', layout=[
        [sg.pin(sg.Button('LOAD', key='-LOAD-POST-')),sg.Push(),sg.pin(sg.Text(f'#10', key='-POST-COUNTER-TEXT-'))],
        [sg.pin(sg.Column([], size=(700, 600), key='-COL1-', scrollable=True, vertical_scroll_only=True,expand_y=True, expand_x=True,element_justification='c'))],
    ], key='-MAIN-FRAME-')],
]

window = sg.Window('Problem - playing video in PySimpleGUI', layout, size=(800, 600), grab_anywhere=True,font=('Montserrat', 9, 'bold'), element_justification='c')
while True:
    event, values = window.read(100)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if firstTime:
        for i in range(10):
            window.extend_layout(window['-COL1-'], [post()])
            window.refresh()
            window['-COL1-'].contents_changed()
            counter += 1
        firstTime = False

    if event == '-LOAD-POST-':
        if not counter >= 40:
            for i in range(10):
                window.extend_layout(window['-COL1-'], [post()])
                window.refresh()
                window['-COL1-'].contents_changed()
                counter += 1
                window['-POST-COUNTER-TEXT-'].update(f'#{counter - 1}')
        else:
            # print('Enough for today!')
            window['-POST-COUNTER-TEXT-'].update(f'#{counter - 1}(MAX)')


    window.refresh()
    print(event)

window.close()
```

when user click the load button 10 more frame with a image(which i want to be a video),and play/pause button will be added(max : 40)

i want to display video in the `-content-{counter}-` when user click the play button for that video.
`-TIMER-{counter}-` is the length of the video and the current time (e.g. 01:50 / 03:10).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the Demo Program Demo_Media_Player_VLC_Based.py.  It will play video and sound using VLC.

Comment: I read that but I don't know how to implement it for myself. @Mike